# JavaScript String Template Literals does not work in Angular Expressions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, string

I am playing with [String Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) of JavaScript with AngularJS. It seems like string template literals are not supported by [AngularJs Expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression). Here's the code which I am playing with

```
<body ng-app>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <input type="text" ng-model="temp">
    <p>{{ 'Text in the text box: ' + temp }}</p>
    <!--This does not work.-->
    <!--<p>{{ `Text in the text box: ${temp}` }}</p>-->
  </body>
```

Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ihRxmKpMpIPCOaFtX4sX?p=preview). Does anyone know why they are not supported. or am I missing something. And is there anyway I can get template literals working in angular expressions.

Comment: I guess because not all browsers support ES6, yet. And transpiling tools like Babel are not expected to recognize every single piece of JavaScript in your code base (especially in your views).

Comment: <p>Text in the text box: {{ temp }}</p> would work though, right?

Comment: @rrd I know this would work. I am curious to know about ES6 template literals with expressions this is why I posted this question.

Comment: @HiteshKumar: IMHO, angularjs way of using `{{...}}` is already an interpolation technique. Why double it?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Agree with you. I was just playing with it and saw this behaviour so I shared. Anyways I understand what you mean. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

**String Template literals Browser Compatibility :**

[image]